# Finding all sum of 2 power value combination values of a given number in R

Tags: r

R data frame 1 :

| Index | Powervalue |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 4 | 16 |
| 5 | 32 |

R dataframe 2 :

| CombinedValue |
| --- |
| 20 |
| 50 |

Expected Final Result :

[image]

Can we get the output as in the image. If yes please help.

One of stackoverflow mate provided below code. Am looking how to seperate , values as columns with 1 and 0.

```
df <- data.frame(sum = c(50, 20, 6))
values_list <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  sum <- df$sum[i]
  values <- c()
  while (sum > 0) {
    value <- 2^floor(log2(sum))
    values <- c(values, value)
    sum <- sum - value
  }
  values_list[[i]] <- values
}
df$values <- values_list
```

Can we fix columns till power 31 as shown in attached image. The columns match with possiblecodes then place 1 and 0 else 0 for the remaining columns. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Why isn't column `code_8` in your expected output?

Comment: Code_ columns are list of unique values from possiblecodes column

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function whose output matches the expected output.

```r
toCodes <- function(x) {
  n <- floor(log2(x))
  pow <- rev(seq.int(max(n)))
  # 'y' is the matrix of codes
  y <- t(sapply(x, \(.x) (.x %/% 2^pow) %% 2L))
  i_cols <- apply(y, 2, \(.y) any(.y != 0L))
  colnames(y) <- sprintf("code_%d", 2^pow)
  #
  possiblecodes <- apply(y, 1, \(p) {
    codes <- 2^pow[as.logical(p)]
    paste(rev(codes), collapse = ",")
  })
  data.frame(combinedvalue = x, possiblecodes, y[, i_cols])
}

x <- c(20L, 50L)
toCodes(x)
#>   combinedvalue possiblecodes code_32 code_16 code_4 code_2
#> 1            20          4,16       0       1      1      0
#> 2            50       2,16,32       1       1      0      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Can we fix columns. If the possiblecodes is available then place 1 and 0 else fill entire column with 0. Can we do something like this